# Handle comma and double quotes inside the field value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to perform some operations on the csv file but there has a problem at the beginning.

I have a csv file like this:

```
id,order_id,name1,name2,code,product_name,qty,price,transaction_datetime
1590621,S21001730,"ABC_FT_WM Boot","ABC-BOOT CLOSUR",,"[A2HYS1431]6" PREM BOOT,FQ",1,1529.20,"2021-03-06 18:48:41"
```

The product_name has comma and double quotes inside the field value. And I tried to fix this.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=',(?![^"]*\")',engine='python')
df.to_csv('test2.csv',na_rep='',sep=',', index = None)
```

But the result is:

```
id,order_id,name1,name2,code,product_name,qty,price,transaction_datetime
"1590621,S21001730,""ABC_FT_WM Boot"",""ABC-BOOT CLOSUR"",,""[A2HYS1431]6"" PREM BOOT,FQ"",1,,1529.20,""2021-03-06 18:48:41"",
```

This is fail.
So I change my code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

n=9
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",usecols=range(n),lineterminator='\n')

df.to_csv('test2.csv',na_rep='',sep=',', index = None)
```

I still fail but better than before. All fields meets the standard except the product_name "[A2HYS1431]6" PREM BOOT,FQ" become [A2HYS1431]6 PREM BOOT,"FQ"""

The 6" disappear the comma and ,FQ get the new double quotes.

I hope the result like this:

```
id,order_id,name1,name2,code,product_name,qty,price,transaction_datetime
1590621,S21001730,"ABC_FT_WM Boot","ABC-BOOT CLOSUR",,"[A2HYS1431]6" PREM BOOT,FQ",1,1529.20,"2021-03-06 18:48:41"
```

Is there a way to handle comma and double quotes inside the field value?

Comment: This is from database. Because I am doing the data clean, some data is missing.

Comment: How did you get the CSV file from a database?  Maybe there's a problem with that part.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be there now.  Either I mis-copied it or you edited it.

Comment: There are different CSV dialects w.r.t. quoting `"` inside a field.  One is to double it like `""`.  Another is to use an escape character--something like `\"`.  But if you have neither, then the parsing is ambiguous.  So I think you have a problem with the generation of the CSV file itself.

Comment: If the commas are only inside the `product_name` i suggest using `quotechar='\''` and wrap all `product_name` values inside single quotes. Other than that your csv file is really ambiguous and you should change the delimiter to something else e.g. ';'